# UIView cant be accessed from different method

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I declare a a uiview in my header file of a uiviewcontroller like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *loadLoading;
```

And initiate itin viewdidload:

```
loadLoading = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
loadLoading.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubView:loadLoading];
```

This works fine. But at another point in my program i want to remove this subview. But for some reason, it doesnt get removed.

```
NSLog(@"%@",loadLoading.backgroundColor);
[loadLoading removeFromSuperview];
```

(I know it gets to that point and loadLoading is accessible because the log does work.

Comment: Have you tried `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` after your `removeFromSuperview`?

Comment: @yeesterbunny yeah still not working. This is very strange.

Comment: hmm....where exactly is this `removeFromSuperview` been called? Can you also do a check like: `if(self.view == loadLoading.superview) //log something`

Comment: Is `loadLoading` null?  If so, there will be no complaint when it encounters `[loadLoading removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: @bobnoble The `NSLog(@"%@",loadLoading.backgroundColor);` works, so it cant be null

Comment: @yeesterbunny i did that and the log did show. I cant think what the problem may be

Comment: Is it possible that its a thread issue? I call the method that calls `removeFromSuperView` from a `NSNotficationcenter` observer..

Comment: Are you allowing the compiler to automatically `@synthesize` `loadLoading`? If so, the compiler defaults to naming the instance variable `_loadLoading`, and the `loadLoading` you're using might be a variable local to the `viewDidLoad` method, which would explain why you couldn't access it later. Still, that wouldn't explain the background color log working...

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the `NSLog(@"%@",loadLoading.backgroundColor);` worked.

Then this code `[self.loadLoading removeFromSuperview];` should be work, else there is some weird bug.

Here is another approach:
Add a tag to the view when you add it to the parentView.

```
loadLoading = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[loadLoading setTag:7];
```

Use that tag to remove it from the parentView.

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:7] removeFromSuperView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

I didnt provide enough details in my question. I was calling this method from notificationcenter, which loads on a different thread. So i had to first do `performSelectorOnMainThread` which worked

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
[self.loadLoading removeFromSuperview];
```